# Group-by statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

So currently, I have the following table:

```
ID, Name, Code, Date
1   AB    x1     01/03/2014
1   AB    x2     01/04/2014
1   AB    x3     01/05/2014
2   BC    x3     01/05/2014
2   BC    x5     01/06/2014
3   CD    x1     01/06/2014
```

I want the following output:

```
ID, Name, Code, Date
1   AB    x3     01/05/2014
2   BC    x5     01/06/2014
3   CD    x1     01/06/2014
```

So basically, I just want the latest date, without caring for the code.

In my code, I have

```
select id, name, code, max(date)
group by id, name, code
```

But the group by does not work as it's also going to take the code into consideration, thus I don't get just the latest date. Also, I can't leave code in the group by statement as it'll give me an error.

How do I use a group by without including code?
I'm using PL/SQL developer as IDE.

Comment: What would you want to get if you have several records with same max(date)?

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name, code, date
from (
  select id, name, code, 
         date,
         max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
  from the_table
) 
where date = max_date;
```

If you want to pick exactly one of the dates if there are multiple "max dates" you can use `row_number()` instead:

```
select id, name, code, date
from (
  select id, name, code, 
         date,
         row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as rn
  from the_table
) 
where rn = 1;
```

---

Btw: `date` is a  horrible name for a column. For one because it's also the name of a data type but more importantly because it does not document at all what the column contains. An "end date"? A "start date"? A "due date"? ...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is latest updated record right?

```
select t1.* 
from table t1 
inner join (select id, name, max(date) as latest_date
            from table
            group by id, name) t2 on t1.date = t2.latest_date 
            and t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name
```

It will be good to have index on date column

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to get whatever the code is that is on the row that has the max date.  If you truly don't care what code gets returned, just use an aggregate function on it like max(code).

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.code, t2.date
FROM MyTable t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 1 code, date
  FROM MyTable t3
  WHERE t3.id=t1.id
  AND t3.name=t1.name
  ORDER BY t3.date DESC
) t2
```

I'm not sure if CROSS JOIN is PL/SQL compatible, but you can find the equivalent, I'm sure.

Comment: Oracle does support `cross join` - but a cross join does not make any sense here. A regular join would be better. But Oracle does not support `top` and there is no PL/SQL in your code.

Comment: A cross-join absolutely makes sense because the OP did not provide a unique key to join on.  Without a unique key, a regular join could produce multiple rows. So "Row_Number() OVER (Partition By..." is PL/SQL?   It looks a lot like TSQL.   I admit I don't use Oracle so I provided the best ANSI SQL answer I know.

Comment: `row_number()` is a so called "window function" and is ANSI SQL. It has been available in Oracle since version 8 (and many other DBMS support that as well - actually SQL Server was pretty late to that party). I still think a regular join (see Faraz' answer) would be the better choice if no window functions were to be used. Not necessarily for performance reasons but for clarity. PL/SQL in Oracle is strictly for stored procedures. Anything that doesn't start with `declare` or `begin` is not PL/SQL.

Comment: Faraz's answer absolutely won't work because there could be multiple rows with the same name/id/date combination, so the resultset could contain more rows than expected/desired.

Comment: Now that I know that Row_number() is available, I do agree it's the best solution.

Comment: We don't know if Abhinav wants to have multiple rows if the same id/maxdate combination occurs more than once (it's essentially my first query).